# Extract LSB bit from a Byte in python

Tags: python-3.x, byte, extract, lsb

I have a byte in variable 'DATA'. I want to extract the LSB bit out of it and print it.
I'm very new to python, I found many articles with complex bitwise addition logic and all which was very tough to understand.
I'm looking for a simple logic like we do with the strings eg DATA[7:1]
Please help me out...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is your "byte" an `int`? If so, just take bitwise AND (`&`) with `1` (or, if you want to be more explicit, the binary literal `0b1`) to get the least significant bit.

```
>>> x = 14
>>> x & 1
0
>>> x = 15
>>> x & 1
1
```

Is your "byte" a `bytes` object? If so, just index into it and take bitwise AND.

```
>>> y = bytes([14, 15])
>>> y[0] & 1
0
>>> y[1] & 1
1
```

Comment: @Nikhil When you read a file in binary mode (`rb`), you get a `bytes` object from `file.read()`. To find the least significant bit, take bitwise AND with `0b1`. Note that you will need to figure out which parts of the file are header and which parts are actual image data. It may help to use a library like PIL.

Answer (score 8):

Simplest and probably fastest:

`least_significant_bit_of_x = x & -x`

You can find more tricks here: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1959565

Although the go-to reference for bitwise "black magic" is Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming, vol. 1".

Answer (score -2):

Right shift by the number n and take the last bit by and 1

```
num >> n &1
```