# How to extract the LSB from a byte in C and Python?

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, python-3.x, arduino

I'm sending a byte to my Raspi 3 and my Arduino via Bluetooth Serial.

e.g. `0b00000011` (mode), `0b01000001` (mode), `0b10010000` (direction)

The LSB indicates if the byte is a direction command or a instruction to switch mode, so I need to extract it in Arduino C and in Python.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341338/extract-lsb-bit-from-a-byte-in-python

Comment: `value&1` in both languages.

Comment: The usual way to extract the value of certain bits of a number is to mask off the other bits with a bitwise "and" operation.  Python and C spell that operator the same way: `&`.

Comment: Turn the integer into a [*binary* string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin); get the last character, convert back to int.

Comment: @wii that's just horribly inefficient.

Comment: @gre_gor - how about: integer mod 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bit operation:

**C code**

```
char b = 0x01;

if( b & 0x01 ) {
   // LSB is set
}
else {
   // LSB is not set
}
```

**Python code**

```
b = 0x01
if (b&0x01)==0x01 :
    # LSB is set
else:
    # LSB is not set
```

LSB = **L**east **S**ignificant **B**it (in your case)

Comment: This error appears: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    if ( b & 0x01 ):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bytes' and 'int'

Comment: Ok great, do you know how to do it in python?