# How can I get the Least Significant Bits of every RGB pixel values of a video in python code? I want the LSB to be in binary form

Tags: python, video, binary, rgb, steganography

I have attached the code below. In this code, I want to write a section to get the binary LSB values from the RGB value of frames.
Frames - The video is fragmented into respective video frames

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

vidcap = cv.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
if not vidcap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = vidcap.read()
     # -------------------------------------------------------------> step 2 - split
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print(gray)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
vidcap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is your *frames* looks like?  You may find this helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341338/

Comment: `frame` is a numpy array, most likely 3d, i.e., width x height x 3 (the width and height might be switched around, I don't remember). Iterating over all its elements is trivial. To get the binary **string** of a number, use `bin()`. But you can directly extract and modify bits from integers using [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). For example, [extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220959/python-how-do-i-extract-specific-bits-from-a-byte) and [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173774/how-to-modify-bits-in-an-integer) a bit.

Comment: Also be careful that the numpy array stores the colours of a pixel in BGR order. That's the 3 in the `width x height x 3` size.

Comment: @Reti43 I have converted the 3d frame into a 2d numpy array but I am getting TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. I have attached that part of the code below:   
    width, height, d=frame.shape
    print("reshaped...")
    frame_reshp = frame.reshape(width*height,3)
    w, h = frame_reshp.shape
    for i in h:
        for j in w:
            print(frame_reshp[i][j])